# Strange Streaks on Samsung CJG50 Monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

all!
I have two Samsung CJG50 monitors, which I mounted to an arm last night. One's 6 months old, the other right out of its packaging.

When going from dark grey to a lighter colour, streaks will appear across the screen along the top of the area of lighter colour. These streaks move with the content onscreen. While it's more noticeable on the older monitor (it wasn't before), I'm surprised it's showing on both, as it's fairly unlikely that something was done which would damage both. I have since tried the monitor with a Fire Stick to ensure it wasn't the computer or cables - same effect was noticeable. I haven't found any videos or mentions of this phenomenon anywhere online, which makes its appearance in two monitors even stranger.

[I recreated the effect in Photoshop as I couldn't get a good photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz9Dm.jpg)
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would wonder if it could some sort of electromagnetic interference. You could try one of the monitors in a different room to see if it is any different

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I moved it to a different room and the artefacts still show up. Contacted Samsung support  and they just recommended a repair (or two)